# File upload fails for files which contains semicolon (;) in filename

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I'm trying to upload a file to an API with `URLSessionUploadTask` using method

```
uploadTask(with request: URLRequest, fromFile fileURL: URL) -> URLSessionUploadTask
```

Everything works perfect until file name doesn't contains semicolon.

When file name contains semicolon app start crashing with following error -

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot read file at
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E647A171-A7CE-46D8-BE81-DB3626DD0157/Library/Caches/downloads/04405877-1554-744f-92ac-379c76300cd8/C8D67486-B79F-44C7-9295-768F0D4D0323/appium%20!@%23$%25%5E&*-+=%7B%7Dl%5B%5D%20;'.,*%20%20;%20logs%20-%20Copy%20(1).ppt'

FileName example which leads my app to crash:

"***appium !@#$%^&_-+={}l[] ;\'.,_  ; logs - Copy (1).ppt***"

"**;.pdf**"

"**];.ppt**"

Please help if anybody ran into same problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with replacing **;** to **some text**, and server side again with **some text** to **;**

*Example :-*

if (filename contains ;) then filename replace with "SEMICOLON".

*Application side when upload file :-*

Real file name = **";.pdf"** 
New name when upload the file = **"SEMICOLON.pdf"**

*Server side when save file in database :-*

File name within response = **"SEMICOLON.pdf"** 
New name when save in database = **";.pdf"**

Comment: As I mention anything excluding semicolon works fine and Sever is not in my control so I can't replace any text with ";"